# Inconsistent behavior between gcc and clang when c++20 concepts are involved

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Does anybody know about inconsistency below? where **gcc** and **clang** behaving differently when **c++20 concepts** are involved.

Basically declared `concept` in **gcc** is able to find my custom `operator==` even through it is declared after the `concept`, but it isn't the case for plain functions( *with user defined names* ). Whereas the `concept` in **clang** in both cases aren't able to find any of my declarations unless they are declared before the `concept`.

And the main question is: **"Which compiler has correct behavior?"**

**NOTE THAT:** both compilers are working fine if all of my declarations declared before a `concept`.

- **Output**: /// *gcc-10.2* and *gcc-11*

  ```
  EqComparable=1
  Comparable=0
  ```
- **Output**: /// *clang-11* and *clang-12*

  ```
  EqComparable=0
  Comparable=0
  ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
concept EqualityComparable = requires( T1 t1, T2 t2 ) { t1 == t2; };

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
concept Comparable = requires( T1 t1, T2 t2 ) { compare(t1,t2); };

std::string operator==( const std::string&, const std::regex& )
{
    return {"hello"};
}

std::string compare( const std::string&, const std::regex& )
{
    return {"hello"};
}

int main()
{    
    std::cout << "EqComparable=" << EqualityComparable<std::string, std::regex> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Comparable=" << Comparable< std::string, std::regex > << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is correct. gcc just has issues with lookup for operators.

In both of your concepts, we are doing lookup for a name: `operator==` in one case and `compare` in the other. We first do regular unqualified lookup and then do argument-dependent lookup.

In both cases, both lookups *should* find nothing: there are no viable candidates found by unqualified lookup (nothing declared before the `concept`s that unqualified lookup could find) and no viable candidates found by ADL (we only look in the associated namespaces, which would be `std`, but your candidates are not in `std`, they are in the global namespace: `::`). Having no candidates, both concept checks should fail.

However, gcc just finds your `operator==` anyway. It shouldn't though, that's incorrect.

This is why:

> NOTE THAT: both compilers are working fine if all of my declarations declared before a concept.

Because now regular unqualified lookup finds the candidates in question.